# Simple regular expression in gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a little problem. I have "some text 23%", but I need "some text ; 23%", so I tried replacing " " for " ; ".

I tried something like this:

```
"some text 23%".gsub /(\d+)%/, "; \0"
```

Problem is in response, in console it is ok, but when I use it in script I have:

```
"some text ; ^@"
```

And I don't know what do with ^@ for have good value.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
"some text 23%".gsub(/(\d+)%/, "; \\1%")
```

You can find more information about making back references to the captures in the ruby documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub

Comment: Thanks Luke, but $1 is empty ; /

Comment: Hi vayneyks, I've updated the answer and checked it on ruby-1.9.3 (from a script)

Comment: I have one more question

In my project I need put regexp and value to change in file. I try get in from .txt file, but it don't work - it is string, and when I convert it to regexp I have problem with polish words, and see '\u0142' instead 'ł'. This is realy important for me ; / Can anybody help me?